# cURL is not working in PHP (NGINX, PHP 8.1, Ubuntu)

Tags: php, nginx, curl, php-curl, php-8.1

I have a cURL-based script for sending push notifications to iOS. While it works perfectly on my local machine, I'm encountering issues when running it on an AWS EC2 instance. The instance is running Ubuntu (22.04.3) and aaPanel (6.8.30) with NGINX (1.21.4) and PHP (8.1.21).

Whenever I execute the script on the AWS EC2 instance, I encounter the following error message:

```
b"\0\0\x18\x04\0\0\0\0\0\0\x01\0\0\x10\0\0\x03\0\0\0\x01\0\x05\0\0@\0\0\x06\0\0\x1F@\0\0u\x07\0\0\0\0\0\x7Fÿÿÿ\0\0\0\x01Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: POST /3/device/[deviceTokenCensored] "
```

After researching online, it seems that enabling HTTP2 could potentially resolve the issue. I noticed that when I checked `phpinfo()`, the status of HTTP2 under CURL was "No". It's worth noting that the website hosted on NGINX is SSL activated. However, I haven't been able to find a definitive solution for enabling HTTP2.

Here's the code snippet that I'm currently working with:

```
$keyfile = public_path("/ios/AuthKey_7QL8QAY5X2.p8");
$keyid = "something";
$teamid = "something";
$bundleid = "something";
$url = "https://api.push.apple.com";
$token = $deviceToken;
$payload = json_encode([
    'aps' => [
        'content-available' => 1,
        'alert' => [
            'title' => $title,
            'body' => $message,
        ],
        'sound' => 'default',
        'badge' => 0,
    ]
]);

$key = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://" . $keyfile);

$header = ["alg" => "ES256", "kid" => $keyid];
$claims = ["iss" => $teamid, "iat" => time()];

$header_encoded = base64($header);
$claims_encoded = base64($claims);

$signature = "";
openssl_sign(
    $header_encoded . "." . $claims_encoded,
    $signature,
    $key,
    "sha256"
);
$jwt = $header_encoded . "." . $claims_encoded . "." . base64_encode($signature);

$http2ch = curl_init("$url/3/device/$token");
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_HTTP09_ALLOWED, 1);
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "apns-topic: {$bundleid}",
    "authorization: bearer $jwt",
    "apns-push-type: alert",
]);
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($http2ch);
if (curl_errno($http2ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($http2ch);
    Log::error("error_msg are: " . $error_msg);
}

if ($result === false) {
    throw new Exception("Curl failed: " . curl_error($http2ch));
}
```

Comment: Pretty wiered given the setup that there is no HTTP2 support enabled for the curl extension. But nevertheless, you need to have it, as the server you sending to only supports HTTP2. Contact customer/technical service of the system you're connecting to and talk about your HTTP 1.1 protocol requirements.  Additionally contact your hosts support and engineering staff to ask for an upgrade for the curl library, that might be the vendor of that panel software you delegate to. See as well: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: An please provide reference for _"After researching online, it seems that enabling HTTP2 could potentially resolve the issue."_. Why do you think so? What made you thinking this way? Additionally: Which version of the curl extension and which version of libcurl are you using? Why do you set CURLOPT_HTTP09_ALLOWED ? For what is this for in context of your question? Perhaps obtaining PHP 8.1.22 may also get you the curl lib upgraded, as for it.

Comment: I am the server admin, and unfortunately, I couldn't locate any method to activate HTTP2. I attempted to upgrade cURL, but it appears that I am already using the most up-to-date version available for Ubuntu.

Comment: I used CURLOPT_HTTP09_ALLOWED as without that it was throwing error ``Curl failed: Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed.``

Comment: That sounds like fishing in the wrong sea, understand the original error message instead of overriding it. https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP09_ALLOWED.html And it remains, your php 8.1 (also I don't have .22 yet on Ubuntu 22.04) needs HTTP2 support in curl, AFAIK this needs to be available in libcurl/curl extension compile. Here my output: `php8.1 -i | grep HTTP2\\\|cURL \n cURL support => enabled \n cURL Information => 7.81.0`. Have you tried rebuilding the cUrl extension with HTTP2 support enabled?

Comment: This was missing in my last comment from the output (naturally the important part, doh: `HTTP2 => Yes`).

Comment: can you force it with `curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0)` ?

Comment: I did add ``curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0)`` but it was not working. Finally, I installed Ubuntu 20 and the issue was solved. Installed Ubuntu 22 in many instances of AWS and was facing same issue.